# Winter bash icon keep having a [1] in front of it even tho I already clicked on it

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I came across a bug, in the top right of the screen I always see this:

[image]

An extra `1` on the winter bash icon, it doesn't go away een if I click on it.

Comment: **Already reported [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357921/1-new-hat-notification-doesnt-go-away) and being worked on.**

Comment: @CodyGray Oh wow, I am not the only one who is experiencing this bug lol :-)

Comment: Nope. It's affecting pretty much everyone. I'm surprised you're the first to have reported it here on MSO, frankly.

Comment: I've not got this issue and I have just got 11 hats. Why is it failing for all of you?

Comment: @TheGrandJ Do you see, "You have earned the right to run fast and jump for joy..." highlighted in your hat drop-down list? It seems to be highlighted again each time I refresh.

Comment: @CodyGray I actually don't have that hat